# Autofac with class library

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a C# solution containing

```
-MVC project
-WCF Project
-Service library
-Model (Entity Framework)
```

The MVC Project is getting all the data from the web service.
And the WCF Service is getting the data from the service library.

Im now trying to implement DI with Autofac.

What i done so far is to created tree classes in the service library.

```
public class ServiceModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Foot.Service"))
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}

public class EFModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType(typeof(FootContext)).As(typeof(IContext)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}

public class Init
{
    public Init()
    {
        //Autofac Configuration
        var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new EFModule());
        var container = builder.Build();

    }
}
```

Is this the right way to go? And then call the Init() in the WCF library?

And should i do the same thing for the WCF service?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I can see two applications in your solution. The first application is the MVC project. And the second application is the WCF service. The other projects are class libraries and not applications.

What you need to do is make sure that only applications have [Composition Roots](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), i.e., only applications should compose objects at their entry point.

Quoting from the referenced article:

> Only applications should have Composition Roots. Libraries and frameworks shouldn't.

So, the only places where you should reference a DI container is the two mentioned applications. So, in your case, this means that you should register the types from the Service and Model libraries in the WCF service project. The Service and Model libraries should not have any reference to the DI container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the code i showed should be in the WCF Service? And in the MVC project the DI for the WCF service?

Comment: Yes, since the WCF service in this case is the application.

Comment: When should i then call the init() from WCF? On every call? Or if i create it as a windows service then on start of the web service?

Comment: @determig, the composition root for WCF services is a custom ServiceHostFactory class. Let your WCF service classes declare their dependencies in their constructors. And then build a custom ServiceHostFactory will correctly build such services. Google "ServiceHostFactory DI" for more details.